# React Google Gantt chart performing style recalucation when hovering for tooltip

Tags: react-google-charts

We are seeing a performance issue with the react google charts wrapper and the use of Gantt charts. running the performance profiler, it looks like when the Gantt is trying to render the tooltip on bar hover, it performs a style recalculation of alla the bars. This means, the larger the number or bars the more recalucaltions cousing longer delays on showing the tooltip.

Tried this on the sandbox app and seeing the same thing. has anyone found a workaround for this?
https://www.react-google-charts.com/examples/gantt#no-dependencies
[Chrome Performance Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIhWx.png)

tried to disable tooltips but cant be done.